# Best way to fetch the data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am making a simple react application in which I am in the need to display user list in select dropdown.

This user list comes from api.

So I am using Context API in my application and I have made a context and made the api call inside the context.

**context.js**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function Provider({ children }) {
  const getUsers = () => {
    return axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10`).then((res) => {
      return res;
    });
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ usersList: getUsers() }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**users.js**

-> Just including context where user data has been fetched and included [**react-select**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) for dropdown.

-> Using `useContext` getting the promise value and inside `useEffect` hook getting the response and storing it in a state variable `setUsers`

-> In render method returning the select box values with the fetched users list as dropdown.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { UserContext } from "../context";

const Users = () => {
  const { usersList } = useContext(UserContext);

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = () => {
    usersList.then((users) => {
      setUsers(users.data.results);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p> Below user list in select box is called from API </p>
      <Select
        value={""}
        name="user"
        options={users}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name.first}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.id.value}
        className="basic-multi-select"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Users;
```

**Working example:**

[image: Edit React Context API (forked)]

**Query:**

-> This works fine **but** in my real application this leads to `multiple api calls`.

-> I have checked in network tab and it has been called for at least 50 times and I feel that this will be a big issue regarding peroformance.

So I would like to know if there is a much better and standard way of implementing this in order to avoid memory leaks and multiple calls for an api fetch?

I am suspecting whether this line,

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{ usersList: getUsers() }}>
```

causing the real issue as I am calling  `getUsers()` method with parathesis `()` but if I remove it the it doesn't get executed..

Please kindly help me and thanks in advance..

Comment: https://react-query.tanstack.com/

Comment: make it async and await it?

Comment: I think the Users and Provider you show here work fine. Let's take a step back and check where you call the Provider component. Is there anything miswork that cause the Provider component to be mounted and unmounted more than once?

Comment: From what I can see here and from your codesandbox, the `getUsers` will only ever be called if `Provider` is rerendered, and since `Provider` is wrapping everything in `App` it will only ever be called if your entire app is rerendered. You could *not* immediately invoke `getUsers` and just do the call in `Users` when the component mounts, i.e. `usersList().then((users) => { setUsers(users.data.results); });`, or do something like @iagowp's answer. When do you want `getUsers` to be called?

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks for your comment bro, will check for the below modified solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the user list in an array, and have your components call `getUsers` on mount. Then just use `users` wherever you need

```
export function Provider({ children }) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const getUsers = () => {
    if (!users.length) {
      axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10`).then((res) => {
        setUsers(res.data.results);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ usersList: users, getUsers }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

On User.js

```
const Users = () => {
  const { usersList, getUsers } = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, [getUsers]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p> Below user list in select box is called from API </p>
      <Select
        value={""}
        name="user"
        options={users}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name.first}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.id.value}
        className="basic-multi-select"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This gives empty userList array https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-api-forked-v31k5

Comment: @Undefined You need to get `getUsers` in your component, and call it inside a `useEffect` with an empty array for dependecy

Comment: @Undefined I've changed my answer to be more complete